# Importing xsl into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, import

I'm trying to import an xsl spreadsheet file into a SQL server table using the SQL Server export and import wizard. However, it failed to import and returned following messages:

Validation:

```
Validating (Warning)
Messages
Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "ObjectName" with a length of 255 to database column "ObjectName" with a length of 31.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "ShortDescription" with a length of 255 to database column "ShortDescription" with a length of 75.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "ObjectName" with a length of 255 to database column "ObjectName" with a length of 31.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "ShortDescription" with a length of 255 to database column "ShortDescription" with a length of 75.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Warning 0x80049304: Data Flow Task 1: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

While copying:

Copying to [dbo].[tblReports] (Error)
Messages

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.tblReports' with unique index 'tblReports$SheetName'. The duplicate key value is ().".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - tblReports.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - tblReports.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - tblReports" (56) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (69). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

[image]

[image]

How can I get this working?

Comment: Have you tried to import into test table that does not have any constraints or keys?

Answer (score 0):

For these two warnings:

> Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to
>   inserting data from data flow column "ShortDescription" with a length
>   of 255 to database column "ShortDescription" with a length of 75. (SQL
>   Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Warning 0x802092a7: Data Flow Task 1: Truncation may occur due to
>   inserting data from data flow column "ObjectName" with a length of 255
>   to database column "ObjectName" with a length of 31. (SQL Server
>   Import and Export Wizard)

You should increase the column size because it looks like you have data that isn't falling within the constraints of the column.